# RSE increases when RSS decreases (relative to increase of number of predictors)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression

In Intro to Statistical Regression (Python) on page 88 "RSE can increased when newspaper is added to the model given that RSS must decrease." Newspaper is just another predictor.
The text says that if the RSS decreases in a relatively small amount compared to the increase of the number of predictors. I can't think of any example for this. Could someone provide an example.